# Does Android TV remote always have a back button?

Tags: android-tv

Does Android TV remote always have a back button, or do some manufacturers do not include it? The reason I as is I am developing an app for it and want to decide to include a back button in UI or not.

Comment: AFAIK, if there is no back button on the remote, the TV should have an on-screen back button, much like phones.

Comment: @Puspam On the contrary, Android Phone have a guaranteed back button, on which developers rely on.

Answer (score 0):

Two major Android TV boxes I know of are Nvidia Shield TV (which I use) and Xiaomi Mi Box. By checking the remote control of my Nvidia Shield there is a back button. Looking at images of the remotes of other Android TV boxes such as Ematic Jetstream, these also have an independent back button on the remote control.

[image]

It appears most if not all Android TV box manufacturers include a back button on their remote controls.